# How to control the visibility of the top and/or bottom pager in DevExpress ASPxDataView

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, visibility

I am trying to control the **visibility for the pagers on the top and the bottom of the DevExpress ASPxDataView** control.

One can control the visibility of both the pagers at the same time using the following setting for the control:

```
PagerSettings-Visible="false"
```

I am trying to find a way I can control the visibility of the header and the footer pagers of the control separately. Like having the header pager only and vice versa.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine [PagerSettings.Position](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxPagerPagerSettingsEx_Positiontopic) property with [PagerSettings.Visible](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxPagerPagerSettingsEx_Visibletopic) property. [PagerPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pagerposition.aspx) is ASP.NET enumeration.

Comment: Thanks, Filip. I was just not paying that much attention.